# What are the English equivalents for 民宿, 农家乐 and 网红打卡点？

Tags: translation, culture

Searching the info of travel, I have seen the above words many times and known roughly what they meant.

I saw a sign in both English and Chinese put on the wall of the information center of a tourist spot,showing that the operator is one of the members of a national Homestay association (Apparently,it is the official name of the organization,where homestay is used for 民宿.)But as far as I know, homestay means the guests would stay together with the host family, which is different from the business model we see in China-they only provide home space for accomodation without food and other service.

With regard to 农家乐, is it a brand name for packaged tourism or what?

About 网红打卡点,does that mean a place is frequented by online celebrities or influencers?

Comment: 民宿 can be like Airbnb, which also markets itself as a homestay provider. 农家乐 is more akin to agriturismos and farm stays (but agriturismos might be primarily Italian?) - can often also just be used for dining though too.

Answer (score 0):

**What is -**

**民宿:**

民宿，原本指將自有住宅的空閒房間出租，並且由主人與其家人負責清掃、訂房、接待客人等服務，經營用客房不超過4層、建築面積不超過800 ㎡。現在泛指私人經營的小型旅館，通常房間不如商務旅館多，也不一定有接待櫃台與穿著制服的服務人員。因為規模小，以往民宿不常有網路訂房系統和刷卡等服務，但現在也有不少國家的民宿有參加大型的國際訂房網站並接受信用卡。https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E6%B0%91%E5%AE%BF

**农家乐:**

农家乐是新兴的旅游休闲形式，一种回归自然从而获得身心放松、愉悦精神的休闲旅游方式。一般来说，农家乐的业主利用当地的农产品进行加工，满足客人的需要，成本较低，因此消费就不高。而且农家乐周围一般都是美丽的自然或田园风光，空气清新，环境放松，可以舒缓现代人的精神压力，因此受到很多城市人群的喜爱。(“ rural tourism; farm -based tourism; agritainment; agritourism farm; farm resort”). https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%86%9C%E5%AE%B6%E4%B9%90/17777 & https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%9C%E5%AE%B6%E4%B9%90

**网红打卡点/地:**

网红打卡地最直白的解释就是一个地方在网上火了，然后很多人都想要去到那里然后拍张照片发到朋友圈或其他社媒。https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/371179175

Example: 深圳光明文化艺术中心，已成为新的**网红打卡地**了.

- Shenzhen Guangming Culture Center has become a new **Instagram-Worthy Location**.

Comment: Good, but why Instagram not Tumblr? Tik Tok sounds more like it.

Comment: Yes, it can be any app that has direct picture-taking and broadcasting functions, but Instagram could be the earliest app to be wildly used at the beginning of the trend.